# C# Multiple Screen View Single Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, show-hide

I created a GUI in C# which should look like this:

On Main Screen there are two Buttons, When `Button1` is clicked I don't want to open a new form using `form2.show();` but while staying in the same form I want to change display.

I did this using hiding GUI elements and showing the other elements as required.

It works fine as I wanted but in the designer View of `Form1` I had to create messy GUI.

My question is that is it good programming practice or not? If not then what is the best or recommended way to achieve this.

thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using a tab control? Would give same/similar functionality whilst keeping your designer view more tidy

Comment: thanks, tabbing can also be used you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to consider a 'Tabless' tab control, I tend to use them for a lot of my work these days as it's easy and quick to build an interface using the win-forms designer with them.

```
    class TablessTabControl : TabControl
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            // Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
            if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !DesignMode) m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
            else base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

This will extend the tab control and hide the tabs along the top, you can then change tab programmatically by using code similar to the following:

```
    tablessTabControl.SelectTab("tabName");
```

This isn't my original work, I found it floating around the web a while back and can't remember where I saw it. Anyway I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this seems more close to what I am looking for. I will give it a try and discuss it or comment further.

Comment: Hi, I added this class in the project but it didn't hide the tabControls. Do I need to add something more?

Comment: @user1809095 Yes, you need to make sure that you create a TablessTabControl in your winforms application. If you look under the ToolBox menu within Visual Studio you should notice a section with the name of your project followed by components, e.g. WindowsFormApplication2 Components. Just drag and drop the TablessTabControl out of your toolbox onto your windows form like you would normally using a regular Tab Control. From there you can manage it like you would a regular Tab Control.

Comment: Thanks again, I was looking into ToolBox but didn't find TablessTabControl because I am using MS Visual C# 2010. I should download Visual studio and try your way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Express 2010 with C# and it's displayed without a problem for me. The other option is for you to drag and drop a regular Tab Control onto your form, expand the form with the + icon next to it in the Solution Explorer. Right click on the <formname>.Designer.cs . In your case it should be Form2.Designer.cs  and view code. Search through the source for the tab control declaration - something like `this.myTabControl = new System.Forms.TabControl();` and change it to `this.myTabControl = new TablessTabControl();`

Comment: It worked Perfect. Really thankful for your time. Stay blessed

Comment: This does not work in .NET Compact Framework 3.5. TabControl and his parents have no such a method as WndProc.

Answer (score 1):

how about using TabControl, you get all the 'views' you want without messy 
visible = `true/false` shizzle.

Comment: thanks for quick response, TabControl is one of the option but personally I don't like tabbing. So in this case when one wants to avoid tabbing also. Is this messy designer the right way or not? or is it the last resort?

Comment: that depend, if you are hiding many controls, you might want to use panels to group up your controls, and make those visible/not. But there are many more ways to do it. If it is like 1-2 controls, then your way is really a way to go, if not you have really alot of ways to do it.

Comment: thanks, I think I would need to use tabs/panels if there are many controls which needs to be shown/hidden with each different view. But for now, I can use it now. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You could create different child controls View1 and View2 and Show/hide each control based on the form state and the button clicks.

Comment: But these views will again be overlapping in the same form designer View and will be look messy. Isn't it?

Comment: I dont understand why you are so overly worried about designer view. However, a work around for your "mess" coould be to add these controls one after the other, so your form looks very long. And when you decide to show/hide the controls, you can also set their top and left positions so that they show up properly.

Comment: Hmm what i was doing so far was a work around, I am not worried I wanted to know the best practice in this regard. In case sometimes later someone needs to work on my code he will be 'praising' me, if i leave the designer like this. But I would like to try your approach that you just mentioned.

Comment: I do not know about best practices, but a good practice is encapuslation. It is better to group together basic controls that are related into a single user control, so that you can use show hide on a smaller piece of code. As other posters have mentioned, TabControls, Panels, etc are different grouping options that you have and should explore further.

Comment: you are right, really thanks a lot for nice suggestions at least you guys gave me some more dimension to design and think of different layout depending upon the requirement. thankful to you all